# Sort by Started Letter

Tags: node.js, mongodb

get data by started letter form mongodb using nodejs

```
let letter = req.params.letter || 'a';

let allMoviesStartedWithLetter = await Movies.find({name : {$regex : 
'^{letter}', $options: 'i'}}).count();
```

Want to pass letter variable to $regex anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the RegExp constructor to make your regular expression:

```js
new RegExp(`^${letter}`, "i")
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

> Using the constructor function provides runtime compilation of the regular expression. Use the constructor function when you know the regular expression pattern will be changing, or you don't know the pattern and are getting it from another source, such as user input.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, simply concatenate the string:

```
let letter = req.params.letter || 'a';

let allMoviesStartedWithLetter = await Movies.find({
    name : {$regex : '^'+letter, $options: 'i'}
}).count();
```